# What is the Akka streams .via() equivalent in Project Reactor?

Tags: java, scala, project-reactor, akka-stream

I'm kind of struggling with the Project Reactor documentation. I have some experience in Akka Streams but right now I'm working on a project that uses Project Reactor.

I need a Reactor operator that has the ability to accept a sequence to pass the message through. It needs to behave similarly to the .via() operator in Akka Streams.

For example, say we have a sequence of: A -> B -> C and I need to inject the sequence X1 -> X2 -> X3 after the B step. So the final sequence would be A -> B -> X1 -> X2 -> X3 -> C.

Does something like this exist in Reactor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closes to `via` in Project Reactor is the [transform](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#transform-java.util.function.Function-) method.

So in Akka say you have this graph:

```scala
Source.single(10)
      .map(_ * -1) //some mapping
      .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

and then you have this flow:

```scala
val flow = Flow[Int].map(_ * 2)
```

you can plug in that flow to your graph like this:

```scala
Source.single(10)
      .map(_ * -1)
      .via(flow)
      .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

The equivalent in Project Reactor would be this:

Having a graph:

```java
 Flux.just(10)
     .map(x -> x * -1)
     .subscribe();
```

and a method to transform a `Flux<Integer>` into a `Publisher<Integer>`:

```java
public static class Transformers
{
  public static Publisher<Integer> flow(Flux<Integer> f)
  {
    return f.map(x -> x * 2);
  }
}
```

you can plug in that method into your graph like this:

```java
Flux.just(10)
    .map(x -> x * -1)
    .transform(Transformers::flow)
    .subscribe();
```

I wrote a post on this and other differences between the two APIs, perhaps you'll find it useful. This post is from 2019 and the APIs evolve. For example I mention `compose` method in context of `Flux` that has been renamed to `transformDeferred` since I wrote this, I am not sure what else drifted since I authored the post, so be warned: [Akka Streams vs Project Reactor API](http://voee.tech/blog/akka-streams-rxjava2-project-reactor-api-comparison)